# How to return string value of state in hook?

Tags: rust, yew

Returning string state in use_effect_with_deps gives error.

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use yew::prelude::*;


#[hook]
pub fn use_hook_test() -> String
{
    let first_load = use_state(|| true);

    let hash_state = use_state(|| "".to_owned());

 
    let hash_state_clone = hash_state.clone();
    use_effect_with_deps(move |_| {
        if *first_load {
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {

                    hash_state_clone.set(format!("{:?}", "Hello"));
                
            });

            first_load.set(false);
        }
        || {};
    }, ());

    hash_state_clone.deref().clone()
}
```

Error:

```
let hash_state_clone = hash_state.clone();
   |         ---------------- move occurs because `hash_state_clone` has type `yew::UseStateHandle<std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
14 |     use_effect_with_deps(move |_| {
   |                          -------- value moved into closure here
...
18 |                     hash_state_clone.set(format!("{:?}", "Hello"));
   |                     ---------------- variable moved due to use in closure
...
27 |     hash_state_clone.deref().clone()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Comment: At the time `use_hook_test` returns the future hasn't even run yet. You should consider returning the state `hash_state` instead.

Comment: Duplicate?, Related?: [How to create a request and use the data from an async request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74868994/442760)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Yew Playground](https://play.yew.rs/?shared=tf2B5gESyx3MqBesM46z) based on your example with some minor changes:

- added an explicit scope to isolate the `use_effect_with_deps`
- added a second `hash_state.clone()` after that scope

The result is somewhat nonsensical but compiles ok.

```rust
#[hook]
pub fn use_hook_test() -> String
{
    let first_load = use_state(|| true);
    let hash_state = use_state(|| "".to_owned());
    {
        let hash_state_clone = hash_state.clone();
        use_effect_with_deps(move |_| {
            if *first_load {
                wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                    hash_state_clone.set(format!("{:?}", "Hello"));
                });
                first_load.set(false);
            }
            || {};
        }, ());
    }

    let hash_state_clone = hash_state.clone();
    hash_state_clone.deref().clone()
}
```